# Why won't my trigger arrow key event work in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am trying to set up a function that creates an alert every time I click the right arrow or the left arrow in Javascript.

```js
    function arrowFunction(event) {
      var x = event.key;
    
      // If the pressed keyboard button is "a" or "A" (using caps lock or shift), alert some text.
      if (x == "37") { 
        alert ("You pressed the 'left' key!");
      }
    }
      if (x == "38") { 
        alert ("You pressed the 'left' key!");
      }
    }
```

```html
    <p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 
    
    <div id ="container">
      <div id ="animate" onclick="myMove()" onkeydown="arrowFunction(event) ></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you missing " on this line onkeydown="arrowFunction(event) ></div>

Comment: You are missing a quote mark after onkeyddown=... in your html, and in your script you have an extra close }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues going on.

1. You never added a closing quote on the onkeydown attribute.
2. You have to have a tabindex on the div (and focus on it) in order for it to receive the keydown event.
3. There are various ways the key can be read. Using `code` gives you a string (like I added). If you want to use the numbers, then use `event.which`. Take a look at [this](https://keycode.info/) for more details.
4. You have an extra `}` brace in your JS.

```js
function arrowFunction(event) {
  var x = event.key;
  console.log(x);
  if (x == "ArrowLeft") { 
    alert ("You pressed the 'left' key!");
  }
  // You had an extra slash here
  if (x == "ArrowRight") { 
    alert ("You pressed the 'right' key!");
  }
}

function myMove() {}
```

```css
#animate {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
Click the box to focus on it...

<div id ="container">
  <!-- You are missing the end quote here. Also need a tabindex -->
  <div id ="animate" onclick="myMove()" onkeydown="arrowFunction(event)" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay since i did not understand that you want click left or right buttons or pressing left and right arrow keys on keyboard to get the trigger i gave the code for both situations :

For "Pressing" event you need to put the trigger on  element on HTML

```
<body onkeydown="arrowFunction(event)">
```

And the following JavaScript

```
function arrowFunction(event) { var x = event.key; if (x == "ArrowLeft") { 
    alert ("You pressed the 'Left' key!");
  }
  if (x == "ArrowRight") { 
    alert ("You pressed the 'Right' key!");
  }
}
```

For "Clicking" event you need to create TWO button elements and put the onClick event on them

```
<button onclick="arrowFunction('left')">Left Button</button>
<button onclick="arrowFunction('right')">Right Button</button>
```

and the following JavaScript

```
function arrowFunction(event) {
        var x = event;
        if (x == "left") {
          alert("You pressed the 'Left' key!");
        }
        if (x == "right") {
          alert("You pressed the 'Right' key!");
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have changed/added?